# code and IB frame doesnt match

Tags: iphone, xcode, cgrect

Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100878/ipad-frame-programmatically-doesnt-match-with-ib but no-one answered!

I created a UITableCell layout in IB, copied done the measurements of the UILabel frame and used them to programmatically resize the frame.

But the Y coordinate is out by about 13 pixels - WHY?

Frame in IB x:176 y:16

Frame in code to match X:176.0f, y:3.0f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your autoresizing masks and Origin positions.

[image]